# Django object is not iterable in a queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm just trying to get the index of the position in the for by using a iterator but I get the error  `object is not iterable`.

Then how can I get the index position in the for loop?

```
user_event = UserEvent.objects.filter(event=obj.id).order_by('id')
for i, user in user_event:
    u = UserEvent.get(id=user.id)
    u.pos = i
    u.save()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) instead:

```
for i, user in enumerate(user_event):
    u = UserEvent.get(id=user.id)
    u.pos = i
    u.save()
```

Comment: Though I'm still not sure what exactly are you trying to do here and what is the motivation.